Consumer stability problem with RabbitMQ and EasyNetQ in C#
I've been having problems with stability in my consumers. I currently have a system that has 5 consumers in the same process working in parallel. They connect to Rabbit and appear to do work for a time. Then instead of new incoming messages being "ready", the "unacked" count on the queue rises and "ready" stays at zero. As far as I can tell, the channel is still open, and no errors were logged.
The code is as follows:
public class DatabridgeRequestConsumer : BackgroundService
{
    //This number represents the maximum execution width, and the maximum level of out of order operation
    private const int NUM_CONSUMERS = 5;

    private readonly DatabridgeQueueInfrastructure _queueInfrastructure;
    private readonly string _requestQueueName;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _sp;
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<DatabridgeRequestConsumer> _logger;
    private readonly EventController _eventController;

    public DatabridgeRequestConsumer(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<DatabridgeRequestConsumer> logger, DatabridgeQueueInfrastructure queueInfrastructure, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _queueInfrastructure = queueInfrastructure;
        _requestQueueName = queueInfrastructure.requestQueueName;
        _sp = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_requestQueueName))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Environment variable RABBIT_LANREQUEST_QUEUE is not set.");
        }

        _eventController = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<EventController>(_sp);

    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        List<IDisposable> disp = new();
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                await _queueInfrastructure.EnsureInfrastructureAsync();

                var advancedBus = _queueInfrastructure.advancedBus;
                var responseRoutingKey = _queueInfrastructure.responseRoutingKey;

                var queue = _queueInfrastructure.requestQueue;

                for (var c_idx = 0; c_idx < NUM_CONSUMERS; c_idx++)
                {
                    var consumerindex = c_idx;
                    _logger.LogInformation($"[{consumerindex}] Subscribing to queue: {_requestQueueName}");

                    //Note that the Consume function is Async, but doesn't look like it
                    disp.Add(advancedBus.Consume(queue, async (messageBytes, properties, info) =>
                    {
                        if (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            _logger.LogDebug($"Cancellation has been requested, returning Nack+Requueue");
                            return AckStrategies.NackWithRequeue;
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes.Span);
                            _logger.LogDebug($"[{consumerindex}] Received message: {message}");

                            var responseMessage = await ProcessMessage(message);

                            _logger.LogDebug($"[{consumerindex}] ProcessMessage responded: {responseMessage}");

                            return AckStrategies.Ack;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            _logger.LogError(ex, $"[{consumerindex}] Message processing failed: {ex.Message}");
                            return AckStrategies.NackWithoutRequeue;
                        }
                    }));
                }
                // Wait indefinitely or until cancellation is requested
                //Note: we don't wait infinitely in a single delay, generally we want to see if the advanced bus is still connnected
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), stoppingToken);

                    if (!advancedBus.IsConnected && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation($"Bus disconnected while consuming on queue: {_requestQueueName}, going around again.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"Connection error: {ex.Message}");
                disp.ForEach(c => c.Dispose());
                disp.Clear();
                await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken); // Wait before attempting to reconnect
            }
        }
        disp.ForEach(c => c.Dispose());
    }

    private async Task<dynamic> ProcessMessage(string message)
    {
        var query = JObject.Parse(message);

        return await _eventController.Query(query, null, _queueInfrastructure);
    }

The incoming queue is a permanent durable priority queue.
I had tried using the RammitMQ Client directly, and recoded the routines using EasyNetQ hoping that the issues would be handled by the library. Currently I'm not at all sure why I keep getting these unacked messages. I'm pretty sure that Rabbit can kick the remote channels from time to time.
How do people generally set up EasyNetQ to offer auto reconnects and basically a connection that's secure and stable for long periods of time?
P.S. I just noticed that the "Unacked" count doesn't even return to zero after the consumers disconnect, nor when new consumers reconnect, what could be happening here?
Thanks.

I noticed that the default Consumer prefix was 50, which probably explains why I can have more unacks than I have consumers. I've now configured the prefetch to 1 for each consumer so hopefully if a consumer goes dead, I might be able to identfy whether it's infinite looped or something.
